Protecting sensitive data in the Terraform state file in an Azure environment
We are developing a GitHub Action to deploy topics, ACLs, and connectors using the Terraform Confluent provider. Authentication is handled through a Service Principal (SPN), and the secrets, such as the SPN’s secret or Kafka API keys, are retrieved from an Azure KeyVault.
Our provider configuration looks like this:
terraform {
    required_providers {
        confluent = {
            source = "confluentinc/confluent"
            version = "1.77.0"
        }
    azurerm = {
        source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        version = "~> 3.95"
    }
}

backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name = "my_resource_group"
    storage_account_name = "mystorageacc"
    container_name = "terraform"
    key = "connectors/ccpre.tfstate"

    client_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.client_id.value
    client_secret = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.client_secret.value
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.tenant_id.value
    subscription_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.subscription_id.value
 }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "confluent"{
    cloud_api_key = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.confluent_cloud_api_key.value
    cloud_api_secret = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.confluent_cloud_api_secret.value
}

We’ve been researching options for securing the tfstate files and it seems that other cloud providers like S3 (AWS) and GCS (Google Cloud Storage) support encryption options that help protect sensitive data in tfstate files https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/sensitive-data.
However, we haven’t found a clear way to apply similar encryption in Azure Blob Storage without potentially disrupting the standard Terraform plan and apply workflows. We’re looking for a way to enable encryption on Azure Blob storage that is compatible with Terraform's requirements or for alternative approaches that ensure tfstate remains secure.

Yes, in Azure, you can encrypt the Terraform state file. Create a dedicated container within an Azure storage account to store your Terraform state files, and enable Azure Storage Service Encryption (SSE) to secure your Terraform state files at rest using either Azure-managed keys or customer-managed keys. For more details, refer to the MS Doc.


Protecting sensitive data in the Terraform state file in an Azure environment

You can encrypt the Terraform state file in Azure in a more secure way.

Create a container for the Terraform state file within an Azure storage account, and enable Azure Storage Service Encryption to secure your Terraform state files at rest using either Azure-managed keys or customer-managed keys.


This way, when you use sensitive information such as client secrets, client ID, subscription ID, and tenant ID, all will be securely stored in the Azure storage account with encryption.

Enable RBAC for authentication in the storage account.


Assign a role such as Storage Blob Data Contributor to the service principal or user to access the storage account, ensuring that only authorized individuals can access the state file.

You can allow the required device IPs in the firewall section, ensuring that only authorized devices have access.


Reference: Securing Terraform State in Azure by Chris_Ayers
Azure Storage encryption for data at rest
Server-side encryption of Azure Disk Storage

I have a question. Let's say I'm a user with access to the blob for which I've enabled the Infrastructure encryption option. If I manually download a file from this blob and read it, will the content be encrypted?
If not, then the only way to protect the secrets that may appear in the connectors' tfstate file would be to ensure proper management of access to the blob in question?

Infrastructure Encryption is an additional layer of encryption applied to the data at rest within Azure's storage infrastructure.When a user downloads a file from Azure Blob Storage, the Azure platform decrypts the file for you before sending it over the network (provided you have the necessary permissions). The file you receive on your local machine will be in its original, unencrypted form.


We’ve been researching options for securing the tfstate files

Terraform just released v1.10. There are new resources called ephemeral resources.
Ephemeral resources's values never gets stored into state file.
It is meant to solve the problem you are facing of storing sensitive value to state file.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.10.x/resources/ephemeral

If you are able to upgrade to Terraform v1.10 and to a similarly-recent version of the hashicorp/azurerm provider then you can use the new Terraform feature Ephemeral Resources to read values from Azure Key Vault without capturing them into the Terraform state.
To do this, you would replace your uses of the azurerm_key_vault_secret data source to instead use the new azurerm_key_vault_secret ephemeral resource type.
ephemeral "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "confluent_cloud_api_key" {
  # (in this block, use similar arguments to what you previously
  # had in your data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "confluent_cloud_api_key"
  # block)
}

ephemeral "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "confluent_cloud_api_secret" {
  # (in this block, use similar arguments to what you previously
  # had in your data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "confluent_cloud_api_secret"
  # block)
}

provider "confluent"{
  cloud_api_key = ephemeral.azurerm_key_vault_secret.confluent_cloud_api_key.value
  cloud_api_secret = ephemeral.azurerm_key_vault_secret.confluent_cloud_api_secret.value
}

What is special about "ephemeral resources" is that Terraform only stores their results in memory during a single operation, and does not persist them anywhere. Terraform will fetch the secrets from Key Vault separately during the plan and apply phases, and therefore doesn't need to save the secret in any saved plan file nor persist it between plan/apply rounds in the state.
Note that this does not cause your state snapshots to be encrypted. Instead, it avoids including the secret values in the state snapshots in the first place, so that it's no longer so important to encrypt the state snapshots. You could still potentially configure your Azure blob storage to perform server-side encryption so that the state snapshots are encrypted at rest, but that would then only be part of a "defense in depth" strategy to avoid exposing the metadata about your infrastructure, since there would not be any true secrets in the state snapshots.

Note also that you cannot use results from data sources or ephemeral resources in a backend block, because Terraform needs to configure the backend before performing any other operations. For sensitive and/or variable information needed for the backend configuration, the most typical strategy is to provide those values in environment variables: ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_CLIENT_SECRET, ARM_TENANT_ID, and ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID.
If you ensure that those environment variables are set then you can omit the corresponding arguments from the backend "azurerm" block altogether.

I tried ussing epheral resources but i have a problem. I have defined in my files some sensitive configurations for the different connectors we use, for example:
config_sensitive = sensitive(merge(
each.value.type == "AmazonSqsSourcePRE" ? {
"aws.access.key.id"     = ephemeral.azurerm_key_vault_secret.aws_key.value
"aws.secret.key.id"     = ephemeral.azurerm_key_vault_secret.aws_secre.value
} : {},
...
))
When executing a plan i get the following error:
"Ephemeral values are not valid in resource arguments, because resource instances must persist between Terraform phases."

Ephemeral values are only allowed in provider blocks and provisioner/connection blocks, so the example in my answer that I adapted from the original question is valid but it would not be valid to refer to either of the ephemeral resources from within a resource or data block. Terraform needs those to persist between plan/apply rounds so that Terraform can compare prior state to desired state when generating the next plan, so there is no way to avoid storing resource attributes in the state.
